# Cakephp acl help: How are aros and acos table created?

Tags: cakephp

I can't understand how are aros and acos tables created.

There are lft , rht columns in aros table.

I have read the documentation of cake acl.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1550/Setting-up-permissions

I also understand when do i need Acl , i can do $this->Auth->allow(..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

they are created [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1546/Initialize-the-Db-Acl-tables). In the cookbook, there's a tutorial just for ACL.

Comment: Why do i need aros acos tables ? I can do $this->Auth-Allow(.. , $this->Auth-Deny(.. . then why do i need $this->Acl-Allow(... ?

Comment: then you don't need ACL, just use Auth.

Comment: I use Auth to allow/deny actions, with Acl can i allow/deny actions ? what else can i allow/deny with Acl ?

Comment: with ACL you can define groups of request objects and what things (actions, resources...) they have access to. It's more powerful than Auth->allow. If you can use Auth->allow just fine, then you don't need ACL.

Comment: so in which situation i must use Acl ? when is Acl must ?  and what do you mean by resources ?

Comment: Read this http://book.cakephp.org/view/1243/Understanding-How-ACL-Works "ACOs could be anything you want to control". Use ACL when you need complex, multi-layered group permissions. Like when you write an app to let people in a big company access the company data.

Comment: What do you mean by multi-layered group permission ? Can you please elaborate with example ? And how can Acl work with company data ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial useful. Hope it helps you too. But I have not check it via implementation.
[How to Use CakePHP’s Access Control Lists](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists/)

NOTE: This tutorial does not follow cake 2.x convention so be careful.